# How can I get more text onto the WelcomeDlg?

Tags: wix

I've got some verbose text that's being truncated on my WelcomeDlg:

[image]

Clearly there's loads of room in the dialog for the extra lines of text, but the text box is too small. How can I make it larger?

Comment: This should help: http://neilsleightholm.blogspot.com/2008/08/customised-uis-for-wix.html

Comment: @YanSklyarenko I tried making a new Dialog `InitialDlg.wxs`, based on WelcomeDlg, and replacing it into all of my `Publish` elements. This didn't work though.

Comment: @YanSklyarenko I've double checked - when I switch out `WelcomeDlg` for `InitialDlg` the installer goes straight to the progress dialog (and nothing happens) when it is launched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at the [source for the WelcomeDlg](http://wix.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/4c2f4b017a65#src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib/WelcomeDlg.wxs) to see what is happening.  The text you are displaying is the `<Control Id="Description" .... />`, but you'll notice there is also another text field below it for describing a patch if it is being applied.

You can customize the WelcomeDlg by following the instructions in the last couple of section of [this page in the manual](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/WixUI_customizations.htm).  Here are some quick steps:

1. Copy the fragment for the WelcomeDlg into your own project from the Wix sources.
2. Change the `Id` attribute of the `Dialog` tag to be unique.  You can then make any changes to the dialog you need (such as making the patch description field smaller and the description field taller).
3. Copy the fragment that defines your UI sequence from the Wix sources into your project.  If you were using the WixUI_InstallDir sequence you would copy [this file](http://wix.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/4c2f4b017a65#src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib/WixUI_InstallDir.wxs).
4. In your custom dialog sequence file you need to change the `Id` attribute of the `UI` tag to be unique and any references to `WelcomeDlg` to the Id you put on your custom WelcomeDlg.
5. In your main package change your `<UIRef Id="..." />` tag to reference the custom dialog sequence.

Comment: In the customized `WelcomeDlg` file, remember to change the `Dialog="WelcomeDlg"` in `InstallUISequence` to the new ID also, and remove the `Overridable` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Not to dismiss your requirement outright,  but I would keep in mind that the attention span of a user running an installer is about that of a 2 year old.  They likely won't read whatever you are putting there in the first place.    Same goes for that EULA that management always wants to make sure the user scrolled all the way through before being allowed to click I Accept.

I follow a minimalist approach when creating installer UI.  Next, Next (if needed), Install, Finish.  Still don't quite like the Install Finish pattern but some do.